# Accessing values in a tuple in a tuple in a list [Error]

Tags: python, list, tuples

I'm using a tool called [ANARCI](http://opig.stats.ox.ac.uk/webapps/sabdab-sabpred/ANARCI.php) to number antibody sequences, and the output of the program looks like this:

```
[((1, ' '), 'E'), ((2, ' '), 'V'), ..., ((113, ' '), 'A')]
```

I am trying to save the numbering in a `.csv` file, and I am having trouble accessing the empty strings shown in the short section above. Some of these will have a letter in them, and I need to check if the string is empty. This is the code I have written to do this:

```
with open(fileName + '.csv', 'wb') as myFile:
    # sets wr to writer function in csv module
    wr = csv.writer(myFile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    # writes in headers
    wr.writerow(headers)
    # iterates through numbering
    for row in numbering:
        # gets to the innermost tuple
        for tup in row:
            # checks if the string contains a letter
            if tup[1] != ' ':
                # makes the number and letter a single string
                numScheme = str(tup[0])+str(tup[1])
                # creates a list of values to write
                varList = [baNumbering,numScheme,row[1]]
                wr.writerow(varList)
            else:
                # if the string does not contain a letter, the list of values is created without the string
                varList = [baNumbering,tup[0],row[1]]
                wr.writerow(varList)
        baNumbering = baNumbering + 1
```

My thinking behind this is `for row in numbering:` gets me to the tuple containing the tuple, and `for tup in row:` would allow me to check the indices of the innermost tuple. I wanted to get `varList` to be a list containing a number, the numbering (possibly with letter attached), and then the letter--like this: `["1","1","E"]` or `["30","29B","Q"]`. However, I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "NumberingScript.py", line 101, in <module>
    Control()
  File "NumberingScript.py", line 94, in Control
    Num()
  File "NumberingScript.py", line 86, in Num
    SaveNumbering(numbering,numberingScheme)
  File "NumberingScript.py", line 72, in SaveNumbering
    WriteFile(numbering,numberingScheme,fileName)
  File "NumberingScript.py", line 51, in WriteFile
    if tup[1] != ' ':
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Is there a better way to access the string in the tuples? All resources I can find only cover a list of tuples, and don't mention what to do with what I have here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception is raising when tup gets 'E' value and you are trying to get an index which doesn't exist.

```
for row in numbering:
            for tup in row:
                if tup[1] != ' ':  # Raised exception --> 'E'[1]
```

If I understand correctly your goals, try to use this:

```
DATA = [((1, ' '), 'E'), ((2, ' '), 'V'), ((113, ' '), 'A')]

def get_tuples(data):
    for item in data:
        for element in item:
            if isinstance(element, tuple):
                yield element
            else:
                continue

for tup in get_tuples(DATA):
    print(tup)
```

Output

```
(1, ' ')
(2, ' ')
(113, ' ')
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my problem with more specificity. However, in the future use the answers section to post actual answers, and use the comments section to post helpful comments which are not answers. Do you know of a way to access only the tuple, and not the string which is causing the error?